# Entering new view after button press (Swift)

Tags: swift, swiftui, view

```
struct EnterOptions: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button(action: {
                //Action here
                } ){
                Text("SIGN UP").frame(maxWidth: 300)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
            }
```

I create a button where I want the user to decide to sign up or login. Just the sign up is shown.

```
struct makeM: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: makeM.ViewModel = .init()
    @StateObject var home: makeM.LoggedIn = .init()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            TextField("Username", text: $viewModel.username)
            TextField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
            TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
            Button("Sign Up", action: {
                Task{await viewModel.signUp() }} )
            Button("Sign In", action: {
                Task{ await viewModel.signIn() }
            })
            //if(viewModel.si == true){
                Button("Sign Out", action: {
                    Task{ await viewModel.signOutLocally() }
                })
            //}
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
```

I want the user to see this screen after clicking the button. I've tried using "makeM()" or putting MakeM() in a WindowGroup() but not sure how I can switch screens for the user using the right syntax. Having trouble in the "//Action Here" part in the first code snippet. Am I going about this the wrong way? Not trying to use storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use NavigationLink if you want to show another screen, but make sure that whole view is wrapped by NavigationStack or NavigationView.

For example:

```
struct EnterOptions: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
    VStack{
        
        NavigationLink {
         // Destination
        } label: {
       Text("SIGN UP").frame(maxWidth: 300)
                .frame(maxHeight: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you know if there's ways to change the animation of the new window appearing and if the back button can be removed?

Comment: For animation I'm not quite sure, but for removing back button just apply `navigationBarHidden(true)` on **DestinationView()**

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer a custom animation for the transition between the views you might have to use a ZStack to present the second view. This post - [How to change views without navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75512163/how-to-change-views-without-navigation) contains an answer that explains the different ways to change views without using the navigation view.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).