# How to change views without navigation

Tags: button, swiftui

I am using swiftui I understand that navigation link is a good way to change view scenes but I need another way to switch from one view to another without using navigation link

This the code I been using to change my view scenes that take me to different view scenes but I need an alternate way to switch views

```
Button{
    
} label: {
    NavigationLink(destination: Gamble()) {
        
        Text("Click Here")
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .accentColor(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what sort of alternate way of "changing" the screen you are looking for? Are you looking to stay on the same screen but change/rearrange the content? Or to present a different screen without using NavigationLink?

Comment: I am trying to go from one view scene to a new view scene @mimo

Comment: you could try using `TabView`
"A view that switches between multiple child views using interactive user interface elements.", ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview

Comment: no that's not what im looking for @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: @Bone there's still a pretty broad range of potential solutions here. What is your motivation for not wanting to use NavigationLink? Understanding that might help narrow down approaches

Comment: the original screen is a sign up screen and with navigationlink it bring the user back to the sign up screen and that's not what im trying to do I have another method I would prefer my user to sign out and naviagtionlink make that hard for me confusing for the user @mimo

Comment: Are you going to do the same trick you did before in your question, 
`How to upload a image to firebase storage`, get the answer then delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using 4 following ways to switch to another view without using the Navigation link:

**1 - Sheet**

```
import SwiftUI

struct View1: View {
    
    @State var isShowView2: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //MARK: -- SHEET
        VStack {
            Button {
                isShowView2.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("View 1")
                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowView2) {
                View2(isShowView2: $isShowView2)
            }
        }
        //MARK: -- FULLSCREENCOVER
        //MARK: -- TRANSITION
        //MARK: -- OVERLAY
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    
    @Binding var isShowView2: Bool
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 2")
                .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
                .onTapGesture {
                    isShowView2.toggle()
                }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**2 - FullScreenCover**

```
struct View1: View {
    
    @State var isShowView2: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //MARK: -- SHEET
        //MARK: -- FULLSCREENCOVER
        VStack {
            Button {
                isShowView2.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("View 1")
                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowView2) {
                View2(isShowView2: $isShowView2)
            }
        }
        //MARK: -- TRANSITION
        //MARK: -- OVERLAY
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**3 - Transition**

```
struct View1: View {
    
    @State var isShowView2: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //MARK: -- SHEET
        //MARK: -- FULLSCREENCOVER
        //MARK: -- TRANSITION
        ZStack {
            Button {
                isShowView2.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("View 1")
                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
            }
        
            if isShowView2 {
                View2(isShowView2: $isShowView2)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
        }
        //MARK: -- OVERLAY
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**4 - Overlay**

```
struct View1: View {
    
    @State var isShowView2: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //MARK: -- SHEET
        //MARK: -- FULLSCREENCOVER
        //MARK: -- TRANSITION
        //MARK: -- OVERLAY
        VStack {
            Button {
                isShowView2.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("View 1")
                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay {
            if isShowView2 {
                View2(isShowView2: $isShowView2)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Hope it is useful for you.

Comment: I got this error Argument passed to call that takes no arguments on                 View2(isShowView2: $isShowView2) @Bao

Comment: Can you tell me which method (1,2,3 or 4) show this error @Bone. I posted the code for method1 within View2's code, but I did not include it in methods 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: it was for method 2 full screen cover @Bao

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the screens in a `ZStack`, then using a `@State` to switch between them?

```
enum Screen {
    case screen1, screen2
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var screen = Screen.screen1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch screen {
            case .screen1:
                VStack {
                    Text("This is screen 1")
                    Button("Show screen 2") {
                        screen = .screen2
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.mint)
            case .screen2:
                VStack {
                    Text("And this is screen 1")
                    Button("Show screen 1") {
                        screen = .screen1
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.yellow)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when I meant change view screens I didn't mean stay on the same view screen I meant a new view screen @AshleyMills

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking in terms of UIKit and view controllers. Adding a frame modifier to the `VStack`s above makes them full screen within the ZStack. I've updated my answer